# rpmbuild giving duplicate file error message

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild

I am trying to build a package for syslog-ng on rhel 8 and keep getting these errors:

```
    File listed twice: /usr/lib/.build-id/53/46b0c98ce522ee7f3ac31c3c1de3bf5f62c873
    File listed twice: /usr/lib/.build-id/62/78b0aa50c592732442979dd4697181da1fca9f
    File listed twice: /usr/lib/.build-id/64/2bdf4d35d74e8db87ebe655657608e0d52b3b2
```

I initial had `%global debug_package %{nil}` in the spec file.  After getting the errors, I tried changing that line to `%define debug_package %{nil}`.  I even tried building the package with `rpmbuild -bi --nodebuginfo syslog-ng.spec`.  All 3 variations still give the error message.  Building a wireshark package with the `%global debug_package %{nil}` doesn't give their error.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=878863

Comment: @totaam Thanks.  I am using the '%exclude' directive in the spec file.